# app.user not recognized upon deployment on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I've got an application written in php7.4, with the framework symfony 5 and I'm trying to deploy this on a standard environment Google App Engine.

The authentication is handled by a login_form and the user_provider (for now) is a in_memory_user provider.
(This won't be the final version, authentication will later be changed, but for now I should have to be able to deploy the app with such config on GAE.)

The security.yaml file:

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    users_in_memory: 
        memory: 
            users:
                userOne:
                    password: userOne
                    roles: ROLE_USER
                userTwo:
                    password: userTwo
                    roles: ROLE_USER
                adminOne:
                    password: admin
                    roles: ROLE_ADMIN
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: users_in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            default_target_path: accueil
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: login
            
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
    - { path: ^/logout, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER] }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Running the app locally, everything works as expected. Once I submit my username and password in the login_form, he sets the 'app.user'. When redirecting to the '**accueil**'-page (which is the base-url **gae-domain/admin**), it recognizes there is a user logged in and the user is granted access to the page.

On the App Engine this doesn't work. It does recognize if you have put in a correct or wrong password, so it does recognize the users_in_memory provider, and it does call the '**/admin**' page right after it if username + password are correct, but he redirects immediately to the login page, because he doesn't recognize a logged in user and so you aren't authorized to access '/admin' page.

I, for the sake of testing, removed the access_control, again now the user has access to the '**/admin**' page, but within the page, nothing is personalized to his role, so again, he can't find a user within 'app.user'.

My app.yaml looks like this (### are replaced with correct info when deploying)

```
runtime: php74

env_variables:
  APP_ENV: prod
  APP_SECRET: ###
  DATABASE_URL: ###

handlers:

- url: /resources
  static_dir: public/resources

- url: /node_modules
  static_dir: public/node_modules
  
- url: .*
  script: auto


basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
```

**UPDATE:**

I see that upon accessing my login page, a session cookie is created (just like when I run it locally). Upon submitting the login-form and having checked the user is recognized in the users_in_memory provider, he deletes this cookie/session_id and doesn't create a new one. That's for me the root cause of why after this, he can't get the info about the logged in user.

When running locally, a cookie is generated before login and after login the previous cookie/session_id is deleted and a new one is created. There everything works fine.

So if anyone knows why no new session cookie/session_id is created after login, that would help. I though maybe this is with the new GDPR regulations that you have to add something somewhere for the user to accept cookies. Or is it just some config I didn't add/change?

Comment: App Engine Standard Environment doesn't supports session affinity if your App Engine Service scale up, your in memory users won't be shared between instances. try to move your strategy scaling to [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#manual_scaling) and set `1 instance`

Comment: Thank you, indeed I've followed the Session Management guide on https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine Standard Environment doesn't supports session affinity if your App Engine Service scale up, your in memory users won't be shared between instances. try to move your [scaling strategy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#manual_scaling)  to manual scaling and set `1 instance`

For future reference as @SimonartM mentioned, it is necessary to handle sessions with the steps that this [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-symfony-on-appengine-standard#session_management) mention.

> To make sessions persist across multiple App Engine instances, you'll need to use a database. Symfony provides a way to handle this using PDO session storage.